# Add Profile programmatically if not present

Tags: experience-analytics

I have a scenario where I need to programmatically set a Profile to the `Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles` if it is not present.

I have tried to achieve this by using `BehaviorProfileConverter` but I rolled back the code. The reason of rollback is because I fear it will cost me in terms of performance as it makes use of **Reflection** to create objects but also, this will need to run each time.

The below snippet is from the `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeInteractionProfile.CopyProfiles` and it is the `BehaviorProfileConverterBase` which makes use of Reflection

```
BehaviorProfileConverterBase profileConverterBase = BehaviorProfileConverterBase.Create();

IList<ProfileData> profileDataList = (IList<ProfileData>)new List<ProfileData>();

foreach (IBehaviorProfileContext profiles in behaviorProfiles.Profiles)
{
    ProfileData profileData = profileConverterBase.Convert(profiles);
    profileDataList.Add(profileData);
}

args.Session.Interaction.Profiles.Initialize((IEnumerable<ProfileData>)profileDataList);
```

Any ideas how to set the ***Profile*** programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Background

While we're at it, I'm going to explain the life cycle of profile objects in xDB.

1. When a new contact is created, its `BehaviorProfiles` property doesn't have any objects.
2. During a session, some profile objects may be added to the current interaction.
3. On session end, profile data will be copied from the interaction to the contact.
4. Between sessions, profile data persists in the "Behavior Profiles" facet of the contact document in the Collection database.
5. In a new session, profile data is loaded as a part of the contact and is copied to a new interaction.
6. Go to step 2.

The take-home point here is that normally you should add new profiles through the interaction API. Later on, this data will be automatically copied to the contact before it is stored in MongoDB.

### Adding a profile

1. Make sure that the profile exists in `Tracker.DefinitionItems.Profiles["YOUR PROFILE NAME"]`. This basically means that the profile should be present under this path:

   ```
   /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Profiles
   ```
2. Simply access the profile like this:

   ```cs
   Profile profile = Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles["YOUR PROFILE NAME"];
   ```

   This will create a profile object if it doesn't exist in the interaction yet. Then you can work with this profile as you normally would.

Comment: Great one. It worked. I always thought that using `Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles["YOUR PROFILE NAME"]` will cause an error if not present